# Java detect long mouse press

Tags: java, swing, events

Is there any way to capture an event if a user press on JList component for more than 3 seconds?

The difficult part i find is the event needs to be trigger even before the user let go of the mouse left button. (which can be easily done by couple mousePressed and mouseReleased)

Comment: All answers (as of 2016) contain deceivingly subtle bugs and should never be used as-is.

Answer (score 5):

You can set a timer in your mouseDown event listener and execute it every 500 ms after an initial delay of 3000 ms. In your mouseReleased you can cancel that timer. On the run method of the `TimerTask` object associated with your `Timer` you can perform the calculation of task you want. Here is my solution proposal:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final JFrame f = new JFrame();
        String[] data = {"one", "two", "three", "four"};
        JList myList = new JList(data);
        f.add(myList);
        myList.addMouseListener(
            new MouseAdapter()
            {
                private java.util.Timer t;
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
                {
                    if(t == null)
                    {
                        t = new java.util.Timer();
                    }
                    t.schedule(new TimerTask()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            System.out.println("My importan task goes here");
                        }
                    },3000,500);
                }

                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
                {
                    if(t != null)
                    {
                        t.cancel();
                        t = null;
                    }
                }
            }
            );
            f.pack();
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    f.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: your code works! just curious... why do we need to put f.setvisible(true); inside a SwingUtilities.invokeLater()?

Comment: This is good, also what would be a nice addition would be that the first click should execute the task and then after that if the user is still mousePressed after 3 seconds then to start the scheduled task every 500ms

Answer (score 4):

Heres what i use for similiar situations:

```
public class Player implements Runnable, MouseListener
{
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        holding = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
        holding = false;
        System.out.println("Held for: "+seconds);
    }
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){}

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            while(holding)
            {
                seconds++;
                // put some code here
                if(seconds==3)
                {
                    holding = false;
                    System.out.println("Held for maximum time!");
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

    private boolean holding;
    private int seconds;
    private Thread thread;
}
```

add this to your JLabel by calling label.addMouseListener(new Player());

Comment: So now you have a holding variable accessed on multiple threads, and if you want to do anything in the UI (which is likely since the user did something on which this code should react) you need to go back from that thread to the UI thread. What is the benefit of all that compared to a simple Swing `Timer`

Answer (score 4):

Two different solutions (nearly the same as the previous ones) :

```java
    new MouseAdapter() {
        Date pressedTime;
        long timeClicked;

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            pressedTime = new Date();
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            timeClicked = new Date().getTime() - pressedTime.getTime();
            if (timeClicked >= 3000) {
                // DO YOUR ACTION HERE
            }
        }
    };
```

or

```java
new MouseAdapter() {
    boolean mousePressed = false;

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mousePressed = true;
                while (mousePressed) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (mousePressed) {
                        // DO YOUR ACTION HERE
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        mousePressed = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have an idea. Its not exactly a listener but what you can do is on `mousePressed` you can make a timer start. When the timer reaches 3 seconds, your event starts or if they let go, on `mouseReleased` the the timer stops.

Answer (score 0):

With this code you can detect and manage pressed long or short (like click), one event excludes another.

```
private int pressStatus = 0; // TO DETECT IF LONG IS REAL LONG OR SHORT PRESSED
private Timer t;

...

@Override
public void mousePressed(final MouseEvent arg0) {
    pressStatus = 0; // to manage simple click or long

    if (t == null) {
        t = new Timer();
    }
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            pressStatus = 1;

            if (t != null) {
                t.cancel();
                t = null;
            }

            // PRESSED LONG
            int modifiers = arg0.getModifiers();
            if ((modifiers & InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK) == InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK) {
                ...
            } else if ((modifiers & InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK) == InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK) {
                ....
            }
        }
    }, 700, 1);
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    if (t != null) {
        t.cancel();
        t = null;
    }

    // PRESSED SHORT LIKE CLICK
    if (pressStatus == 0) {
        int modifiers = arg0.getModifiers();
        if ((modifiers & InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK) == InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK) {
            ...
        } else if ((modifiers & InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK) == InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK) {
            ...
        }
    }

    pressStatus = 0;
}
```