# Java Swing Mouse Held Down Event

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

In my program, I want to be able to click somewhere in a JPanel in order to add objects to the screen.  When the mouse is clicked, an object is created at that point.  If the mouse button is held down for half of a second, then it starts to create objects every 1/10 of a second.  This part works fine.  Code is shown below.

My issue is that when the mouse is dragged across the screen, I would like to get the updated location of the mouse and create an object at that new location instead of where the event was fired.  MouseEvent has the getX and getY functions, but that just returns the location of where the mouse was when when the event was fired.  Any ideas on how to keep the location updated when the mouse is dragged?  Note: The mouseDragged function below never runs.  Any ideas why?

```
//MyClass extends JPanel, and is put into a JFrame before being displayed
final MyClass simulation = new MyClass();
simulation.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);
simulation.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    private Timer timer;

    //Create a new body and add it to the list, then repaint the screen.
    public void createBody(int x, int y) {
        simulation.getBodies().add(simulation.createBody(x, y));
        simulation.repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(final MouseEvent e) {
        if (timer == null) {
            timer = new Timer();
            createBody(e.getX(), e.getY());
        }
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createBody(e.getX(), e.getY());
            }
        }, 500, 100);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
            timer = null;
        }
    } 

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Mouse was moved!");
    } 
});
```

My current code was taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6785701/2953697)

Comment: First use `Swing Timer` instead of `Java Timer` that is more suitable for swing application. Second avoid `setBounds()` and `null` layout.

Comment: for mouse drag use `MouseMotionListener`

Comment: better to start from [How to Write a Mouse-Motion Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html)

Comment: You're violating the single threaded rules of Swing, take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details and switch to using a javax.swing.Timer instead