# Measure how long mouse was held for?

Tags: java, jbutton, mouselistener

I'm working on a game which involves holding on a button. I want to be able to depending on how long a button was pressed for display an image ie:

x = seconds button was held for

if 3.1 seconds > x > 2.9 seconds

then
display image 1

if x < 2.9 or x > 3.1

then
display image 2

How would I program this using a mouse listener?

Thank you.

Comment: It seems like you would want to hook both `mousePressed()` and `mouseReleased()`.  The former would record the last time a mouse key was pressed, possibly on a key-by-key basis, and the latter would compute the time a key was held down as the difference between the current time and the last time it was pressed.

Comment: This could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785385/java-detect-long-mouse-press

Comment: so i should make an image display based in the event mouseReleased() ?

Comment: Not the exact solution shown in that (sigh), you could use the logic behind that. `mousePressed()` and `mouseReleased()`. You could measure the time between the two events.

Comment: would this part be correct to use: public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            timeClicked = new Date().getTime() - pressedTime.getTime();
            if (timeClicked >= 3000) {
                // DO YOUR ACTION HERE
            }

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code snippet to resolve the problem -

```
double startTime, endTime, holdTime;
boolean flag = false;

@Override
public final void mousePressed(final MouseEvent e) {
    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    flag = true;
}

@Override
public final void mouseReleased(final MouseEvent e) {
    if(flag) {
        endTime = System.nanoTime();
        flag = false;
    }
    holdTime = (endTime - startTime) / Math.pow(10,9);
}
```

The holdTime would give you the time in seconds that the mouse was tapped.

Answer (score 0):

There are different opinions about using `System.nanoTime()`.
Have a look : [Is System.nanoTime() completely useless?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510462/is-system-nanotime-completely-useless)

To be on a safer side you can write your own class that counts the milliseconds using `Runnable` interface.

When the mouse is pressed start the Thread containing `Runnable` interface.
And interrupt it when mouse is released.

The `Runnable` class contains the code that counts the time elapsed.

Consider this snippet:

```
public class TimeThread implements Runnable{
    int timeElapsed = 0;
    public int getTimeElapsed() {
        return timeElapsed;
    }
   @Override
   public void run(){
        while(true){
             try{
                 Thread.sleep(1);
                 timeElapsed = timeElapsed + 1;
             }catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                 break;
              }
        }     
    }
}
```

Using the above written TimeThread class to calculate the time elapsed during mouse press and release:

```
       Thread timeCalculationThread;
       TimeThread timeCalculator;

 public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
    timeCalculator = new TimeThread();
    timeCalculationThread = new Thread(timeCalculator);
    timeCalculationThread.start();

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
    timeCalculationThread.interrupt();
    System.out.println("Stopped! time elapsed is "+timeCalculator.getTimeElapsed()+" milliseconds");           
    try {
        timeCalculationThread.join();
        System.out.println("Thread has joined");
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MouseFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```